# Is it possible to add response examples to non-200 responses

Tags: django, drf-spectacular

Is it possible to add `examples:` for non-200 responses, such as 400?

I noticed that using using the same serializer for both 200 and 400 generates the schema correctly, but does not include the example in the 400 response.

```
@extend_schema_serializer(
    component_name="CostResponse",
    examples=[
        OpenApiExample(
            name="A Great Example!",
            value={"field": "Example Value"}
        )
    ]
)
class CostResponseSerializer(Serializer):
    field = CharField(help_text="Thing")


class CostView(APIView):
    """Return the cost of goods sold"""

    @extend_schema(
        summary="Get Cost",
        responses={
            200: CostResponseSerializer,
            400: CostResponseSerializer,
            406: OpenApiResponse(
                response=CostResponseSerializer,
                examples=[ # custom 
                    OpenApiExample(name="Also not included"),
                ]
            )
        },
    )
    def get(self, request):
        pass
```

I would like to include different examples for each endpoint, but getting anything at all would be helpful.

```
  /api/what/:
    get:
      operationId: api_what_retrieve
      summary: Get Cost
      responses:
        '200':
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/CostResponse'
              examples:
                AGreatExample!:
                  value:
                    field: Example Value
                  summary: A Great Example!
        '400':
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/CostResponse'
        '406':
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/CostResponse'
```

Comment: I've given in and written a post hook that adds the example to the `schemas/CostResponse` directly.  I can't find a way to add examples to either schemas or fields in code.

Answer (score 1):

The `OpenApiExample` object contains a `status_code` property that is by default set to `['200', '201']`.

Try something like this:

```py
@extend_schema_serializer(
    component_name="CostResponse",
    examples=[
        OpenApiExample(
            status_codes=['200', '400', '406'],
            name="A Great Example!",
            value={"field": "Example Value"}
        )
    ]
)
class CostResponseSerializer(Serializer):
    field = CharField(help_text="Thing")
```

That way you can specify examples per status codes.